# Displaying Fetch API response in browser window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, fetch, fetch-api

I'm using the Fetch API to query some web services since I need to manually add `X-Custom` headers. All the examples I have found regarding displaying the result use `console.log` into the DevTools console window.

I have no JavaScript experience, but this was a means to an end, so I have:

```
fetch('<url>', {
    headers: myHeaders,
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
}).then(
    function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data)) {
            console.log(data);
        });
    })
```

This does display to console, but I'd like it in the browser window as if I had simply navigated to `<url>` and the response was displayed. Does JavaScript enable something like:

```
fetch('<url>', {
        headers: myHeaders,
        method: 'GET',
        credentials: 'include'
    }).then(
        function(response) {
            response.json().then(function(data)) {
                this.browserWindow.display(data);
            });
        })
```

How would I display it in the browser window as if I had navigated to the URL via the search bar?

**Update**

So I have been successful loading some results as so:

```
fetch('<url>', {
    headers: myHeaders,
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
}).then(
    function(response) {
        response.text().then(function(data)) {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = data
        });
    })
```

And the response appears for inspection; it is a JSON response so I was hoping `response.Json()` would work, but it just displays `[object Object]`. If I can figur eout how to "pretty display" the JSON, we have a solution.

Comment: Could you describe the problem with a little more detail and possibly add some code to express the issue?

Comment: @RhettHarrison I was just updating with code, please see the update

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mostly figured it out, but you can use `JSON.stringify` to get nicer formatting. For niceties, I wrapped the result in the HTML `<pre>` tag, but you can use whatever makes sense for your use case.

```
fetch('<url>', {
    headers: myHeaders,
    method: 'GET',
    credentials: 'include'
}).then(
    function(response) {
        response.json().then(function(data) {
            document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = `<pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre>`
        });
    })
```

There is a security caveat to be aware of. You are adding a response directly to the DOM without sanitizing the results, [which can lead to XSS attacks](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/DOM_based_XSS_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html). While this code is vulnerable, it is probably a minor threat, given your usecase.

For code utilized in production, there is a number of approaches to prevent this vulnerability, the most common being to escape any string you are going to insert into the DOM. An alternative is parsing the results, and creating the HTML elements you wish to insert, using innerTEXT for the content provided from the API.